# Can the verb "code" refer to [producing] any kind of code?

Tags: word-usage

I am a programmer, and I know it is fairly common that we say "to code" to roughly mean "to work with some body of code".

My question is if we can use this word for other kinds of code as well. For example,

> There's something special about that song. It's got a secret message Morse coded into the percussion.

(code, meaning to represent the code) or

> These blades code the character onto the ticker tape each time this rod is pulled low.

(code, meaning to cut the code into the paper) or

> When you speak into this microphone, they will hear your voice next door. Instantaneously it is coded as an MP3 and streamed across the internet also.

(coded as, meaning recorded in the form of)

Comment: I've heard all three uses, though the second (the blade onto the tape) is uncommon.

Comment: to code is to write a program. It isn't "work with a body of code. You write code. "It's got a secret message **in Morse code** in the percussion. The blades one doesn't make much sense to me. What do you mean by "blades"? Generally, codes are not coded. A code is a code. A message is "in code": it is a coded message. It is said to be  encoded.

Comment: @Lambie to my mind, you could code a driver, a function, or database query, not necessarily a program. By blades I meant the sharp metal rods which punch holes in paper. If they're putting a byte or something onto paper tape then could they be said to be coding that byte?

Comment: The point is that to code means to write code. If you code a driver, you are writing code for the driver. About the blades, for me, that sounds odd. If blades punch holes in paper, they are a metal form, aren't they? Each blade corresponds to one thing, doesn't it? They make marks on a  piece of paper....dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `to code` as a means of expressing an encoding of sorts. It would work in example 1 and 3, since `to code` is a synonym of `to encrypt` or `to encode` and because hiding Morse code in a song or converting something into MP3 would be considered that. I personally would use `encoded` in both scenarios, but they are almost identical in terms of their semantics.

Not so sure about the second one though, in my mind 'coding' isn't an action a blade would perform. Perhaps `carving` or simply `writing onto` would be better.

Edit: You could rephrase example 1 to:

> There is a secret Morse code hidden in the percussion.

Comment: Almost identical, not identic.

Comment: @Lambie that's what I said. ^^

Comment: I see the word identic, the al does not appear  on my screen. :)